# Creating an activity calendar in java

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a calendar coupled with activities, for example:
[image]

I was thinking of two abstract classes, the first GroupCalendar would be like this:

```
public abstract class GroupCalendar {

HashMap<TimeFrame, Activity> entries = new HashMap<TimeFrame, Activity>();

public abstract void addActivity(TimeFrame t, Activity a);

public abstract void removeActivity(TimeFrame t, Activity a);

public abstract void findActivity(TimeFrame t);

public abstract void printAll();
}
```

and the second would be Activity class:

```
public abstract class Activity extends GroupCalendar {

private String name, location;

public Activity() {
}

public Activity(String name, String location) {
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
}

public abstract String getName();

public abstract void setName(String name);

public abstract String getLocation();

public abstract void setLocation(String location);
}
```

After that there would be the concrete classes that extend Activity:

```
public class Sport extends Activity {

private String name, location;
private boolean outdoors;

public Sport(String name, String location, boolean outdoors) {


    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.outdoors = outdoors;
}

@Override
public void addActivity(TimeFrame t, Activity a) {
}

@Override
public void removeActivity(TimeFrame t, Activity a) {
}

@Override
public void findActivity(TimeFrame t) {
}

@Override
public void printAll() {
}
}
```

The problem is that I cannot add an activity properly, if I try to add a SPort, all I get is the name and location, no outdoors.
If anyone could give me some hints/pointers about what is wrong with my approach that would mean a lot to me.

Comment: This is too broad and there's very little text explaining anything, which might be a hint that you didn't put enough work in it. Anyway, a place better suited for this kind of questions is [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), post there following my previous advice.

Comment: Can you share the example how you are using it to highlight the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why `Activity` should extend `GroupCalendar`, there is no parent/child relationship between them.

If you want to get `outdoors` just create a getter for it in `Sport`.

Also, what probably your teacher want you to do is to have a method `print` in `Activity`, so any subclass would have to implement it accordingly; for example `Sport` would print `name` + `location` + `outdoor`.
Then you would be able to call `a.print()` where `a` is an `Activity`

Comment: I tried and when I use it in a method, like a.getOutdoors(), where a is Activity object, I get an error.

Comment: Of course, `Activity` doesn't have `getOutdoors()`, you need to cast `Activity` to `Sport` to call that method

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm not sure why you want to use abstract classes for this?

Second, your calendar is made up of activities, an activity should not posses the qualities of a calendar. A single activity does need to have a collection of other time frames and activities, unless activities are made up of other activities.

I would have a concrete `GroupCalendar` class with a concrete `Activity` class and, if need be, override `Activity` methods in sub classes. The `Activity` class should handle the accessing and mutating of `Activity` members, you don't want to override those for every sub class of `Activity`.

On another note, `Activity` has an overloaded constructor that takes `name` and `location`. Therefore, in your `Sport` class' overloaded constructor, you should make a call to `super(name, location)` and remove the not needed assignments.